# Themes and module installation and update scripts give a server 500 error

Tags: 8, updating

In order to upgrade a drupal 6 website without shutting it down during the upgrade process, my provider prepared a new web space without a domain name. (The plan was to transfer the domain name as soon as the new site was ready)
I installed Drupal 8.02 nl (dutch version) using installatron without any problems. However, afterwards I noticed that it was impossible to upload and install themes and modules using the dedicated drupal scripts. The scripts started normally until I had to input my FTP login and password. After pressing "doorgaan" (continue) I receive the following message:

> The website cannot display the page
>
> HTTP 500
>
> Most likely causes:
>
> - The website is under maintenance.
> - The website has a programming error.

On the other hand it was possible to upload the theme and modules manually with a separate FTP program. At that time I didn't pay much attention because I thought that the reason was the missing domain name.

Meanwhile, the domain name has been transferred; the site is operational, but the problem still exists. I also get the same error message when I try to update the manually installed modules. I checked the permissions of the different files and directories, but couldn't find any anomalies

Meanwhile, the drupal version has been updated to 8.04 by installatron and the status report gives an error/warning that the database needs updating.

> Some modules have database schema updates to install. You should run the database update script immediately.

When I click on the database update link, I again get the error message the "page could not be found".

Could anyone help me out of these problems?

Comment: Try setting `$settings['update_free_access'] = TRUE;` in settings.php temporarily? Not sure if there's more to it, if you're able to use Drush instead that would be easier